# Why is my web forms (PHP) not working (Sending email)

Tags: php, forms, email

I have a very simple Contact Us Form below, but it does not seem to be sending email through to my email addresses anymore.  I have a few slightly different PHP files for different forms but they all use the basic rules set below.  Can anyone see any problems?  PHP isn't my strong suit....

```
<form id="form" name="myemailform" method="post" action="submit.php">
     <h3>Contact Us</h3>
     <p>Please use this form to get in touch with us, Thanks...</p>
     <label>Name </label>
     <input name="name" type="text" id="name" />
     <label>Email </label>
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
            <p class="antispam">Leave this empty:<br /><input name="url" /></p>
     <label>Comment </label>
     <textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
     <button type="submit" name='submit' value="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

This uses a simple php script.  By the way, the class `antispam` just hides the `url` field from view by using `display:none;`.  I changed my email address in the example below.

```
<?php

// if the url field is empty
if(isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] == ''){

    // put your email address here
    $youremail = 'MYEMAILADDRESS@hotmail.com';

    $body = "Name     : $_POST[name] \n
    E-Mail   : $_POST[email] \n
    Message  : $_POST[comment]";

    if( $_POST['email'] && !preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $_POST['email']) ) {
      $headers = "From: $_POST[email]";
    } else {
      $headers = "From: $youremail";
    }

    mail($youremail, 'Poiple Shadow - Web Message', $body, $headers );

    header('Location: Thank-You.htm');
}


?>
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- That shouldn't make a difference since I'm pretty sure that the default `type` of an input is text.

Comment: Are you being redirected to the *thank you* page, or not? It is possible that your web host limits the number of emails you can send per day. Try sending a test email and see if it goes through. Also, you can try changing the `isset()` to an `!empty()` function and see if that helps.

Comment: Ok, there's nothing wrong with this code (*tested* via WWW). If you're running this via WWW, make sure `mail()` is available for you to use and check your Spam. Also, if you're running via `localhost` make sure that your server is completely setup for mail/php/etc.

Comment: OP's code checks out @Anonymous I deleted my original comment.

Comment: Also, don't ignore the response of funcitons like `mail()`.  If you were catching a `false` there, you would be one step closer to knowing   whether your web host is delivering.

Comment: Yes, I am getting sent to the 'thank you page',but no email is being sent through. I am pretty sure I am no where near any limit of emails per day (I am likely to get less than 20 a day). I have several forms on different sites hosted on the same server (godaddy) sent to different email addresses with all slightly different configurations and non seem to be working, I have message Godaddy to see if they have changed something, but not heard anything back yet

Comment: ^^^^----- So... why tell us that now? -----^

Comment: if it helps, it's here http://www.poipleshadow.com/Contact-Us

Comment: @Anonymous Seems like I was right from the start LOL! check the [`OP's answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22522718/)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Wow, that makes no sense.  It must be an old version of HTML or something...  Now I'm just confused.  The mozilla website even says it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-type

Comment: @Anonymous I'm just as confused as you. Maybe GoDaddy's got some weird form checking algo running. Unless it's the type of Web browser OP is using (*big question mark*); I'll have to investigate this further.

Comment: I am using google chrome 33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: Seems like I was right from the beginning (*and deleted my original comment*)

Your `<input name="url" />` needs to contain a type which should be `text`.

Change it to `<input type="text" name="url" />`

---

**Edit #2** (My findings on the matter) *March 20, 2014 - 12:20 am*

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.url.html

`type = "url"`
Specifies that its input element is a control for editing an absolute URL given in the element’s value.

---

I quote from: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-email

Written by David Walsh on September 15, 2010

The Advantages to Using type="email" and type="url"

There are a few advantages to using these special INPUT types:

- You may easily style all email INPUT elements with input[type=email]
- You may easily style all url INPUT elements with input[type=url]
- This INPUT type could be considered more semantically correct.
- Mobile accessibility: if your user is browsing with an iPhone and they arrive at a special email input, the iPhone will display a keyboard with the @ symbol provided on the primary screen.  If the INPUT is of type "url", the iPhone will display the ".com" button on the primary keyboard screen:

---

From http://htmlref.labs.oreilly.com/beta/element-input-url.html

HTML: 
XHTML:   or

HTML5 only. Creates a text entry control for entering a single absolute URL. The user agent may validate the data entered to ensure it is in proper URL format and return an error message if it doesn’t match.

Values: text
Specifies the initial value for this control.

---

https://code.google.com/p/chromebackspaceonlinux/issues/detail?id=37

Issue 37: Functionality broken for the HTML5 tag

Reported by glaj...@gmail.com, Jan 16, 2014

What steps will reproduce the problem?
1. Go to a site with an  element (or change any  to  on any site) and hit backspace when focused on that element.

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?
Should delete the character within the input, instead goes to previous page.

What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?
v0.52.0_0 on Linux 3.5.0-32-generic (Mint 15)

Please provide any additional information below.
I have fixed this locally by going to:

```
$HOMEDIR/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/aeffggjddcchloadflonilaahpclmbnm/0.52.0_0/backspace.js
```

And adding the following at line 106:

```
if (target.type == 'url')
    return true;
```

---

From Mozilla.org - https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/11/firefox-4-html5-forms/

Using Firefox 27.0.1, the field lights up in red when typing in `www.example.com` and approves it using the full `http://` call.

---

My prognosis (*but not conclusion*) on the matter is this:

Because the conditional statement is based on the form element's `url`, PHP may not be letting it go through without having a "type" declared.

I haven't found anything on Google yet to support this theory, yet if and when I do, I will be updating my answer as I go.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, it seems to be the **type="text"** that was the issue.  So apparently it does make a difference.  Thanks so much for your responses.

Comment: And I deleted my comment as well as my answer (*now undeleted*). Why did I feel like I was right from the beginning?